# How do I configure a route in Azure without ".aspx" at the end?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

Say, I want to have a page whose URL is "/about", not "/about.aspx". How would I go about doing this, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010? I read some stuff about RewriteRules in ISS but I wasn't sure how to configure it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have a few pages, you can use a url map rewrite rule in `Web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="url map rewrite rule" enabled="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{urlmap:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="urlmap">
        <add key="/" value="default.aspx" />
        <add key="/about" value="about.aspx" />
        <add key="/contactus" value="contact.aspx" />
        etc.
        etc.

      </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really useful. What file should this go in?

Answer (score 4):

The other option is to use [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) instead of Web Forms for your site. This way all urls will have no .aspx at the end.